# Is it possible to log / save a pry session?

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I've seen answers to this question for irb, but not for pry specifically.

So, is it possible to save a log of a pry session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [save](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/History#Hist_save) option to save your session to a file.

Answer (score -1):

It is now:

http://www.github.com/baweaver/pry-session

This will allow for saving sessions in Pry, loading, editing, and listing them.